# Which Module do I use In python to browse, Copy and paste Files in Directories

Tags: python, python-os, python-mode

I want to add a function in my program that when called , opens a browsing window like ones that open when you click on browse to change directory location in a setup. I want it to let me browse through directories , select a file and when I select it,  it has to move that file to a pre-decided location in my system. Is it possible ? And if yes , Which module of python should I study and use .

Comment: Which framework are you using?

Comment: "shutil" can be helpful, too.

Comment: @MichaelButscher, no what he meant was a [file dialog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_dialog). Shutil cannot do that.

Comment: [tkinter.filedialog](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html#module-tkinter.filedialog)?

Comment: @PCM The question consists of two parts: selecting file and moving file. "shutil" can help with the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use pre built shutil library in python to do copy and move actions.

```
import shutil

original = 'Path/To/Folder'
target = 'New/Path'

# Copies Folder
shutil.copy(original, target)

# Moves Folder
shutil.move(original, target)

# Copies Complete Tree
shutil.copytree(original, target)
```

For getting a path by browsing it in file dialog we use prebuilt library named as tkinter like this:

```
import tkinter

# Returns the path to file opened
tkinter.filedialog.askopenfile()
tkinter.filedialog.askopenfiles()

# Returns the path to folder opened
tkinter.filedialog.askdirectory()
```